# Read secrets from file in Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I've created some secrets and I'm trying to import the file in this way:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ template "amq.broker.fullname" . }}-tls
  labels:
    app: {{ template "amq.name" . }}
    chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}"
    component: "{{ .Values.broker.name }}"
    release: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
    heritage: "{{ .Release.Service }}"
type: Opaque
data:
{{ (.Files.Glob "secrets/broker.ks").AsSecrets | indent 2 }}
```

The file is under the `secrets` dir. When I run the install, the `broker.ks` secret is not there. However the secret is under the `secrets` folder. Any idea?

Here the dir struct

```
├── Chart.yaml
├── README.md
├── secrets
│   ├── broker.ks
│   ├── broker_cert
│   ├── client.ks
│   └── client.ts
├── templates
│   ├── NOTES.txt
│   ├── _helpers.tpl
└── values.yaml
```

Comment: What exactly is the error message when you try to `helm upgrade`? What does the dir tree of your chart look like?

Comment: No error during upgrade.

Comment: Does `{{ .Files.Get "secrets/broker.ks" | b64enc | indent 2 }}` work? Or do you require a glob pattern to target more secret files?

Comment: Ah sorry. Misread the secret map. You want the whole content as key/value pairs. Forget my previous comment.

Comment: yep. Trying to achieve this

Comment: Doesn't the glob .asSecrets mechanism create one key per file matching the pattern, with the value of that key being the file's content? In that case you could really try `broker.ks: {{ .Files.Get "secrets/broker.ks" | b64enc }}` - should lead to the same result, no matter what the content of `secrets/broker.ks` is.

Comment: Unfortunately I get this `broker.ks:      0 bytes`

Comment: Nothing is copied

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160021/discussion-between-fishi-and-mazzy).

Comment: where did you put the yaml to install the secret? its not in templates? Helm shows all resources it installs during install/upgrade is it visible in that log?

Comment: @Mazzy did you find a solution for it?

Comment: Can we read data from location outside our chart folder or not ? For example, I want to read date from /etc/certificates folder, is it possible ?

Comment: I tried this, but did not work. {{ $root := . }}
 {{ range $path, $bytes := .Files.Glob “/Users/shabhishek/Desktop/cert.pem” }}
 {{ base $path }}: ‘{{ $root.Files.Get $path | b64enc }}'
 {{ end }}

Answer (score 17):

The solution to this is, as per the [docs](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/#configmap-and-secrets-utility-functions), the following:

```
{{- $root := . -}}
{{- range $path, $bytes := .Files.Glob "secrets/broker.ks" }}
{{ base $path }}: '{{ $root.Files.Get $path | b64enc }}'
{{- end }}
```

You can also pull all the files of a specific type in the folder with `.Files.Glob "secrets/*.ks"`

Also make sure that the folder has not been added to `.helmignore` otherwise the files won't be accessible.

Comment: below configuration is working for me, ```apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-volume-sec
  labels:
    app: {{ .Chart.Name }}
    chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}"
    release: "{{ .Release.Name }}"
    heritage: "{{ .Release.Service }}"
type: Opaque
data:
{{- $path := printf "namespaces/%s/configs/*" .Values.namespace  }}
{{ (.Files.Glob $path).AsSecrets | indent 2 }}``` which also allows me to specify folder based on env.

Comment: It's worth noting that the file path is relative to the chart repository, and not were you "include it".